# Set user roles from phpmyadmin

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

It seems to be something very easy, and yet I am unable to find anything about it. So, I use FOSUserBundle for Symfony2. I registered my user and I want it to have `ROLE_ADMIN`. Since I don't plan to have more admins, I want to set it from phpmyadmin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You will need to add ROLE_ADMIN to your `roles` database field as a serialized array:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}
```

However, that's not the recommended way to promote a user. Instead you can use the following console command:

`php app/console fos:user:promote`